# Flash dynamic shape resizing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I need to create a designer tool in Flash for laying out how kitchen worktops/countertops look. I found something similar to what I need:

http://www.kitchenplanneronline.com/

If you scroll down the page you place a rooms dimensions onto the workspace, and resize it. If you notice, when you resize the shape moves and a measurement shows on each edge.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you keep the drawing separate from the 'tooltip' and you make up a scale that you think fits your design (e.g. 1 m = 100 px)

Answer (score 2):

Program on the page you refer does not seem to work. As I understood you try to change and move measurements each time object is changed. Try to throw events (e.g. "`objectResized`", "`xChanged`", "`yChanged`") in setter of size and coords. And then handle replacing and changing of measurements on those events.